# UIImageJPEGRepresentation generates JPEG without SOI Marker

Tags: swift, jpeg, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I'm generating JPEG image data using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage, 1.0)` in Swift version 4(?).

I'm using a 3rd party JPEG decoder but it throws an error that no SOI (start of image) marker was found.

How do I generate a correctly formatted JPEG with SOI markers in Swift (preferably) or Objective-C?

Is this a known issue in standard Swift and should I start looking at 3rd party JPEG encoders?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the JPEG image data? Or perhaps the problem rests in your third-party decoder? Which JPEG decoder are you using? FWIW, I'm looking at the JPEG created by iOS and I see the SOI there, so I suspect your problem rests elsewhere. But there's not enough here for us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: It is a proprietary decoder for work that is not publicly accessible. I'm going to move forward under the assumption that the fault is in the decoder and not `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolving under the assumption that the fault lies in the decoder and not `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.